# My app file size is already 32Mb

Tags: onclicklistener

I'll start off by saying I am an absolute beginner. I've been following a very good tutorial on YouTube and reading a few books. So far, I have a working app which consists of a splash screen, load up music and then a menu with 6 buttons. I have got these six buttons opening up a new view. I have created a new Java class and a new layout.xml for each new view. Is this right? Basically, all I want to know is how to make an efficient app which allows me to use my 6 buttons to take me to another set of buttons as a sub-menu and then inside those buttons I want to display the information using text and videos and audio. It's a tutorial app. Once I know how to do this then I should be able to continue developing within the app. Any help or ideas please? Since my app is already so large, I'm guessing I've done something wrong, but as I say, the app is working at least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem. My app was 40MB. I found out my music files were too big. I was using `wav` files. When I converted them to `ogg` files, my app went down to 14MB.

This website was useful: http://media.io

The buttons and extra activities probably don't take up that much space. I'm guessing it's the music and maybe any images that you have.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. At the minute I have my intro sound for the splash screen and button click sound which equal 175 KB. I have just noticed that each of my drawable folders have 2 images, one of which is 8 MB, so that times 4 = 32!! Thank you :) I can proceed as before then I think, that is if what I've dsecribed sounds like the right way of doing it?

Comment: you may be able to reuse views that have a similar layout, but I think you can figure that out once you get more comfortable with android development. =] and glad to help!